# jquery append multiple content, just need one them

Tags: jquery, append

a plurality of contents need only one of them.

```
    switch (clickedcount){
        case 1:
            var i = $("<a> 1 content </a>");
            break;
        case 2:
            var i = $("<a> 2 content </a>");
            break;
        case 3:
            var i = $("<a> 3 content </a>");
            break;
        case 4:
            var i = $("<a> 4 content </a>");
            break;
        case 5:
            var i = $("<a> 5 content </a>");
            break;             
    }

    clickedcount++;
    b.append(i);
```

just need only one them.

look this  http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/7/   http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/8/

sorry my eng so bad.

Comment: I did not understand where you need only one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i am unable to understand the question but i think you want to print only one item per click.

`.html()` is used here instead of `.append()`

This will print only one item at per click:

```
    switch (clickedcount){
        case 1:
            var i = $("<a> 1 content </a>");
            break;
        case 2:
            var i = $("<a> 2 content </a>");
            break;
        case 3:
            var i = $("<a> 3 content </a>");
            break;
        case 4:
            var i = $("<a> 4 content </a>");
            break;
        case 5:
            var i = $("<a> 5 content </a>");
            break;             
    }

    clickedcount++;
    b.html(i);
    //^^^^---------html replaces the old content.
```

Comment: yea, but remove one them, this html not change

Comment: yes, i need delete one them, this content number also change

Comment: @DongYifei You need to place the full code or understand the answers given to you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/11/    look this, If you press a few +1 button, i want remove some them, Also followed changes in the amount of content

Answer (score 0):

posted answer and comment in your previous question... check that...

used `html()` and made some modifications in my codes..

anyways..

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/9)

Comment: and more questions i want remove this them. The original three, delete one, left two